# TortoiseGit: Why do some of my branches not have revision numbers?

Tags: tortoisegit

We just started using the revision number feature in TortoiseGit. Earlier today, I noticed that all commits have revision numbers on them, up to the number 310. However, after committing a new branch later, I noticed that the latest commit has the rev number 284. All previous commits do not have numbers unless they are on the same graph flow line.

In short, why do many of these commits have no revision number associated with them? Is there a branch view that will number all of these together?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just discovered the answer. I needed to adjust the branch view. Right click on the below link and click browse to select a new perspective.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Git has no (incremental) revision numbers. You can only try to emulate them, e.g. by counting all commits before - this, however, will not provide unique revision numbers.

> The branch revision number is calculated by calling `git rev-list --count --first-parent [SHA1]` and represents the number of commits between the beginning of time and the selected commit. This number is NOT guaranteed to be unique, especially if you alter the history (e.g., using rebase) or use several branches at the same time. It can be seen "kinda unique" per branch in case you don't alter its history (e.g. by rebasing, resetting) and only commit or merge other branches on it. This number is only displayed for first-parent commits and not for commits on non-fast-forward merges (here duplicate numbers could occur). See https://gcc.gnu.org/ml/gcc/2015-08/msg00148.html and https://gitlab.com/tortoisegit/tortoisegit/merge_requests/1 for more details.

https://tortoisegit.org/docs/tortoisegit/tgit-dug-settings.html#tgit-dug-settings-dialogs

In order to reduce confusions, TortoiseGit does not show them for other than the current branch or for non-fast-forward merges.

Comment: Please consider upvoting and accepting the answer if it helped you, that's the way to say thank you on StackOverflow.